# Virtual Monitor "Off Screen" to Control Remote PC

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control

I'm successfully sharing my Ubuntu Desktop with my Mac Book, using VNC.

My Mac Book Pro is on the right, my external monitor is in the center, and I have an Ubuntu Laptop on the left as in this image:

[image: Example of how my system is laid out.]

While using the Mac, I'd like to be able to slide my mouse to the left of my centre external monitor, so I can think of the Ubuntu system as an additional monitor, as it were.

I have been able to do this from within Ubuntu in the past, by setting up a virtual monitor using "x2x -south -to :1"

I'm curious as to whether this functionality is possible using my Mac.

UPDATE:

I've found the following which are close, but "no-cigar"
https://superuser.com/questions/276766/create-virtual-external-display-for-vnc-control

I've found the following software that might work, though not free:
http://symless.com/synergy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synergy is still open source (therefore free), though they don't really go to great lengths to make that known.

https://github.com/symless/synergy

Synergy works pretty well from what I remember.

Comment: Want to accept soon, @tubedogg-- just having trouble compiling :-/ Mac SDK not found *grr*

Comment: Found it in brew: brew install Caskroom/cask/synergy